# how to get click event on list using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

could you please tell me how to bind click event of list .how to send object on click handle of list in react .here is my code .
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/yOWRqB

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
    this.state ={data: [{hse:'asd'},{hse:'adas'}]};
    this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadFromServer();
    //alert('--')
  }
  loadFromServer(){
   //alert('000000')
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        console.log("=======");
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  }

  btnClick(obj){
    alert('---'+obj)
    this.setState({data: 'nannsd'});
   //  this.state ={data: 'sds'};
  }

  render(){
    return <ul>
      {this.state.data.map(function(item) {
        console.log('---')
        return <li {this.btnClick}>{item.hse}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  }

}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: onClick={this.viewMore.bind(this, attributeId)}

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
     super();
    this.state ={data: [{hse:'asd'},{hse:'adas'}]};
    this.btnClick = this.btnClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadFromServer();
    //alert('--')
  }
  loadFromServer(){
   //alert('000000')
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        console.log("=======");
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({data: data});
      },
      error: (xhr, status, err) => {
        console.error(xhr);
      }
    });
  }

  btnClick(obj){
    alert('---'+obj)
    this.setState({data: 'nannsd'});
   //  this.state ={data: 'sds'};
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map((item) => {
          console.log('---')
          return <li onClick={this.btnClick}>{item.hse}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }

}

React.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

So 2 changes:

- `return <li {this.btnClick}>{item.hse}</li>` => `return <li onClick={this.btnClick}>{item.hse}</li>` to define the event you want to handle.
- `{this.state.data.map(function(item)` => `{this.state.data.map((item) => {` to have correct `this` context.

Comment: thanks @rost  ..But how to sent obj mean Item in click handler

Comment: I need to send the `item` object in `btnClick` function

Comment: You can bind like this: onClick={this.viewMore.bind(this, item)}, however it is not recommended to use bind in render function. I would recommend you to create a new component for ListItem and handle click there. So you will have all the data about list item, coz you will pass it as a prop to ListItem component from your List.

Comment: IMO the LIs need a `key` property in order to allow identification of the individual item clicked.  
This is the purpose of the key.  
I think my linter would complain if there were no key in the map statement.